# Notification Not open Activity onCLick

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to create a notification which should open activity when click on it. But when I click on notification activity not open . 
Here is my code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("payload", payload);
    intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)

    .setContentTitle("Message Received")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentText(payload)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notificationn = notification.getNotification();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationn);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use this:**

```java
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentIntent(getDialogPendingIntent(Text, intentName));

private PendingIntent getDialogPendingIntent(String dialogText,
            String intentname) {
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                dialogText.hashCode(),
                new Intent(ACTION_DIALOG)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dialogText)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                        .setAction(intentname), 0);
}
```

> **getDialogPendingIntent(Text, intentName)** : ***intentName***=com.yourProject.exrta.yourIntentName

You can Change `addFlags` or `putExtra` if you want.

---

**If Call with Intent Name doesn't work use it with class like that and it must work :**

```java
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setContentTitle("Message Received")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(intent);

Notification notificationn = notification.getNotification();
notificationManager.notify(1, notificationn);
```

Comment: I update my code you can check the second way it must working .

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```cpp
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("payload", payload);
intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
.setContentTitle("Message Received")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setContentText(payload)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true);

Notification notificationn = notification.build();
notificationManager.notify(YOUR_NOTIF_ID, notificationn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Context context1 = loggedin.this.getApplicationContext();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context1.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Notification updateComplete = new Notification();

updateComplete.icon = android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sync;

updateComplete.tickerText = context1.getText(R.string.notification_title);

updateComplete.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context1,loggedin.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context1, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

String contentTitle = context1.getText(R.string.notification_title).toString();

String contentText;

contentText = context1.getText(R.string.notification_info_success).toString();
updateComplete.setLatestEventInfo(context1, contentTitle,contentText, contentIntent);

int LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION = 0;
notificationManager.notify(LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, updateComplete);
```